# How to apply accordion jquery effect on this menu bar?

Tags: jquery, menubar, jquery-ui-accordion

I'd like to apply accordion effect on this snippet of code but I'm a beginner in JQuery. Could somebody help me?

```
<div id="left_menu">
            <ul id="main_menu" class="main_menu">
                <li class="limenu" ><a href="dashboard.html"><span class="ico gray shadow home" ></span><b>Dashboard</b></a></li>
                <li class="limenu select" ><a href="#" ><span class="ico gray shadow window"></span><b>Form elements</b></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li ><a href="form.html"> basic form </a></li>
                        <li ><a href="vform.html"> validation </a></li>
                        <li ><a href="wizard.html"> wizard </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="limenu" ><a href="#"><span class="ico gray  dimensions" ></span><b>Sample pages</b></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li ><a href="profile.html"> Profile setting </a></li>
                        <li ><a href="conversation.html"> conversation</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="imagesEditor.html"> Images Editor </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="limenu" ><a href="table.html"><span class="ico gray shadow  spreadsheet"></span><b>Tables</b> </a></li>
                <li class="limenu" ><a href="gallery.html"><span class="ico gray shadow pictures_folder"></span><b>Gallery </b></a></li>
                <li class="limenu" ><a href="#"><span class="ico gray shadow stats_lines"></span><b>Graph and Charts</b> </a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="modalchartLive.html" class="pop_box">live chart </a></li>
                        <li><a href="chart.html">all chart</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="limenu" ><a href="filemanager.html"><span class="ico gray shadow  file"></span><b>File manager </b></a></li>
                <li class="limenu" ><a href="calendar.html"><span class="ico gray shadow calendar"></span><b>Calendar </b></a></li>
                <li class="limenu" ><a href="typography.html"><span class="ico gray  shadow paragraph_align_left"></span><b>Typography</b></a></li>
                <li class="limenu" ><a href="inelement.html"><span class="ico gray shadow abacus"></span><b>Interface elements </b></a></li>
                <li class="limenu" ><a href="map.html"><span class="ico gray shadow  location"></span><b>Map location </b></a></li>
                <li class="limenu" ><a href="icon.html"><span class="ico gray  shadow satellite"></span><b>Icon and Button </b></a></li>
                <li class="limenu" ><a href="404.html"><span class="ico gray  shadow firewall"></span><b>Error Pages</b></a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: you can read jquery ui [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) documentation.

Comment: Check the official demo and documentation: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery UI like so: http://jsfiddle.net/J5jg4/

Answer (score 0):

You should really conform to the HTML format listed in the API:

[JqueryUI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)

So that means a header tag to name the sections, and divs to divide the accordion sections directly after the headers.

But frankly, I'm not sure an accordion is what you're looking for here. If I understand what you're trying to accomplish, don't you really want a simple dropdown menu like this?

[jQuery Dropdown Menu Plugin](http://javascript-array.com/scripts/jquery_simple_drop_down_menu/)